# How to retrieve Custom Settings from Sandbox to a local SFDX Project?

Tags: visualforce, salesforcedx, sandbox, customsetting

I want to know how to retrieve Custom Settings from my Sandbox into a local sfdx project. I know command `force:source:retrieve` but I do not know what parameter to use for retrieving Custom Settings. I have authenticated my Sandbox and tried

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -u MySandbox -m CustomSettings
```

It returned "No result found".

I have tried using Org browser metadata from VS Code, but I could not find anything related to custom settings.

How do I retrieve Custom Settings from my Sandbox?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're the same as a CustomObject. You can retrieve one via the terminal:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:CustomSettingName__c
```

In the Org Browser, they'll also be listed under Custom Objects.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `package.xml` from your manifest folder to include the below code

```
<types>
        <members>CustomSetting__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

Then right click on `package.xml` and select **Retreive Source in Manifest from Org**